# Is there any way to define an exchange in Google Finance separately?

Tags: google-finance

I have stocks from US and Canadian Companies.

I would like to be able to enter the stock symbol and select the exchange in the adjacent column and put the google finance formula and get the current ticker price.

Currently the only way I can get this done is by manually entering the exchange. For Example:
=googlefinance("tse:enb","Name") gets me the name of the stock symbol. I want to be able to enter the ticker symbol in one column and exchange in another column and get the desired output (name in this example) in another column.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could solve this issue by setting up your sheet as follows:

| Exchange | Ticker | Symbol | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NASDAQ | APPL | =JOIN(":", A2, B2) | =GOOGLEFINANCE(C2, "Name") |

and then just duplicating the formulas down as required, to make it easy for copy and pasting, I have put the formulas separately below

Symbol: `=JOIN(":", A2, B2)`

Name: `=GOOGLEFINANCE(C2, "Name")`

If this wasn't what you were looking for, please let me know and I'll try to help again.

Comment: Many many thanks your replying. This solves the problem.

Comment: Great, since my solution has solved your problem, if you don't mind can you mark it as the "accepted answer"?

Comment: I want to but, I don't see that option.

Comment: @TCHTank You can find more information on the site [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)